# How to test a message set by the build config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, tdd

I have a string which is displayed on all of my pages to indicate what mode the system was built in (ie Debug, Beta, Release, etc).  The string is set using compiler conditions (#If in VB) so that it will automatically change based on what build mode we're in.

I wrote a test for this which also uses compiler conditions (exactly like the live code), the problem is, without running my tests under all my different builds, I cannot verify it generates the right string for all the builds.

Here's my code:

```
        Public Sub AssertHasMessageForBuild()
            Dim message As String = Nothing
#If DEBUG Then
            message = "DEBUG MODE"
#ElseIf BETA Then
            message = "BETA"
#End If

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
                Assert.AreEqual(message, ViewData("DebugMessage"))
            Else
                CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain(ViewData, "DebugMessage")
            End If
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD isn't really a mechanism for great testing; it's a mechanism for helping you think about the design and responsibility of your classes.

You might want to separate out the two responsibilities - detecting the mode you're in, and creating the message. You can then TDD the creation of the message, making the mode detection the only part of the system that you can't easily TDD.

You can still test it manually, though. Sometimes that's the only way to go. Just make sure you test it manually again if you ever change it (you might want to add a comment accordingly).

Comment: I was afraid you would say that.